# Managed Property Refinable option is disabled in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-property

[image]

**Scenario**

- I have document lirabry and add a field "TempField" as a metadata type.
- I created a new managed property called "MangProp" which maps to metadata field "TempField"
- now, this "MangProp" option Refinable is disabled.
- so i use default Refinable Property "RefinableString00" and Map "MangProp" property with "RefinableString00"

i also wait for 24h for next crawl but still not works

Thanks

Comment: Where is your Crawled Property coming from? User Profiles or BCS?

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 6):

There are several ready made Managed Properties you can reuse, called RefinableStringNN.

You need to wait (in many cases at least 24h) for the search to crawl content for your change to take effect.

Comment: thanks jussi, can u tell me how much crawl duration? i created before 3 hours still not crawled

Comment: Wait at least 24h, if it still isn't working after that, open support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Not all options are available in SharePoint Online.

In SharePoint Online, when you create a new managed property, it will have some limitations. For example, the property can only be of type Text or Yes/No, and it **can't** be **refinable** or **sortable**.

So as @Jussi said you will have to use the existing RefinableStringNN properties and wait for at least 24 hours for the full crawl.

Refer [Manage the search schema in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-the-search-schema-in-SharePoint-Online-d4fab46d-ba41-4c03-9d4c-32b5b33198b6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) it has got nice details  about managed properties.